# Comma in "still is, and will always remain"

Tags: punctuation, commas, conjunctions, oxford-comma

> Manchester United **still is and will always** remain a force despite these setbacks.

Do I need a comma after *is* here? I personally don't think so but would like to be sure.

Comment: Never mind a comma, you need a new manager.

Comment: But I drove past the Old Trafford stadium two days ago, and it looks a sad and sorry place, anything but 'The Theatre of Dreams'.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use:

> Manchester United **is still, and will always remain,** a strong force despite these setbacks.

Of course, the phrase between the commas can be removed while retaining the original intent of the sentence; however, in this case, the commas tend to also emphasize the idea of 'will always remain.'